# When I use proportional editing the vertices tend to raise without the mesh itself

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, proportional-editing

I have this visual problem that always occurs when I use proportional editing. The vertices tend to raise without the mesh itself. This creates a wireframe effect without being in wireframe mode that's incredibly jarring.

[image: camera sees clip]

This is what happens when I subdivide the mesh.

[image: camera sees quilt-like pattern]

Does anyone know how to solve it, and, better yet, can anyone teach me how to use proportional editing without falling into this pitfall?

[Blend File](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jP1VRVzL)

Latest edit:
I currently believe this problem to be a bug on Macbook version v2.83.4 . Will do the usual updates, debug on different platforms, etc.

Comment: Could you please attach your .blend file from here: https://blend-exchange.com. Also, please take screenshots directly from the computer (If you are on windows just press `Widnows Key` + `Shift` + `S` to take a screenshot) and do not take pictures of the monitor screen, it's confusing. Also, can you show them in solid view edit mode?

Comment: Maybe you have a shrinkwrap modifier and raising the mesh doesn't have a difference.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: I see no problem. I downloaded your file, and everything worked fine. Try copy-pasting objects into a new file and try.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid on my end (but thank you). I wish to view the plane close-up, and on my computer, if the viewport is positioned like a car, the geometry still clips before the camera clips into the plane. If the plane still doesn't clip as described on your end then I might have to replace my computer lol.

Comment: @JamesLowry Try downloading the file you uploaded and opening it again. Maybe your problem is to shade smooth? Otherwise, I do not see any glitches at all. Maybe try restarting your computer or increase your view clipping end distance and decrease your clip start distance by pressing N > View > You'll see the settings on the top.

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry huh... I wonder if that means I'm encountering a bug. Again, no luck upon restart or increasing the clip start distance. Let's  see.. I'm using Blender on Macbook v2.83.4. Let me do the usual: update blender to the latest version on Macbook, try installing Blender on my Windows computer(s), try the files there, etc. I'll update the post accordingly.